# Can I use a power gable fan and ceiling louver vents to pull cool air into my house?

Tags: hvac, fans

I live in L.A.  We only have really hot weather 5-10 days a year and it usually cools off at night (outside). I also have a large Gable vent in my attic. (recently added with addition)

I would like to install a gable fan in the attic and then install louvered vents in my hallway ceiling.  When the gable fan comes on, the ceiling vents would pull warm house air up and out and allow cooler (night) air to come in.

I would like to not use the thermostat and have the unit switched in the house.  This way it would not run during the day.

I have no attic vents around the side of the house or roof vents.

A/C estimates were $7,000+.

Opinions??

Comment: Google "power attic fan" and read the first 20 responses. They are generally frowned upon. If you just had an addition and gable vents why not wait and see how the first summer is?

Answer (score 2):

I had something like this growing up, except ours sucked and did not blow. Air flow was adjusted by how far you opened the window in each room. It worked really well on many of the cooler nights.

Whole House Fan - Lowes lists one as Model #: WH302BDX

Comment: That's the right keyword: whole house fan. I keep thinking of putting one in,  but so far running a strong fan in an upstairs window has worked well enough